# Can I use the gradle connector to get arbitrary configuration information from a build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, tooling

I'm using the Gradle connector with a Gradle project that is downloaded from a service.  I want to do some Gradle operations on that project but need some information from the project.

The downloaded project's build.gradle has some properties that I would like to extract :

```
group = "value0"
archivesBaseName = "value1"
version = "value2"
```

If I use

```
ProjectConnection.getModel(GradleProject.class)
```

I can get some values from the model but not those ones that I want (perhaps I am using it wrong?).  Is there a way to extract those specific values out of the project (perhaps a different model)?  I can also just do some text parsing on the build file, but I'd like that to be my last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradle tooling API only exposes a subset of the build script information, using its own models. As far as I can tell, the properties that you are interested in are not exposed by default. However, you can expose your own custom model. For an example, see `samples/toolingApi/customModel` in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Would I be able to register the Model on the fly with a Project?  From what I understand, Models need to have their ToolingModelBuilder registered with the ToolingModelBuilderRegistry at some point (usually in a plugin's apply implementation).  I don't have control over the service generating the code, so I'd need to do this stuff against whatever is generated.  I need this mainly to implement an AbstractArchiveTask so I can create an artifact from this generated code that depends on this task creating an archive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "register the Model on the fly". You do have to register the model as you described.

Comment: I mean without explicitly registering it in the context of some plugin.  I guess I can't though.  My situation is a little strange.  The plugin I have downloads another project and runs tasks on it using a GradleConnector, I'm trying to extract information from the project.

Comment: A plugin is essentially the same as a build script, except that with the latter, you'll have to use the internal `getServices().get(ServiceType)` to get at a service. You might be able to register the model by injecting an init script, but I'm not sure.

Comment: As Peter wrote: register it in the init script. This is what IDEs do to inject their `ToolingModelBuilder`s.